# Я хочу сменить терминал для вывода codeblocks (cmd) на windows Terminal? Как это сделать? Свойство заблокировано(

Tags: c++, windows, консоль, codeblocks

CodeBlocks по умолчанию все выводит в cmd но я хочу чтобы он выводил сообщения в более удобный для меня терминал - Windows Terminal, но свойство смены терминала заблокировано. Операционная система windows 10.

[image: Заблокированная функция смены терминала CodeBlocks]

Comment: Попробуйте запустить IDE от имени админа. Ещё есть вероятность, что альтернативного терминала [просто не видно в системе](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13900328/3240681).

Comment: CB ничего не знает про этот Windows Terminal (я ведь правильно понимаю, что это который в магазине для Win10?). Для Windows просто прописано в исходниках использовать cmd.exe. А этот выпадающий список предназначен для unix-ов, чтобы можно было выбрать из xterm, rxvt, eterm, aterm и т.п. Если очень-очень надо, можно подправить исходники и вместо cmd указать свой терминал, а потом собрать свою версию CB под Windows, но это не самое тривиальное занятие...

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, вы не сможете изменить терминал по умолчанию в операционной системе Windows, потому что там нет другого.